Nodejs Connection With MySQL database Error: read ECONNRESET
Hi friends
I have a hostinger MySQL live server and I have a react native cli project with the backend is Nodejs with MySQL. Problem is when i connect Nodejs with localhost MySQL then its properly work fine but when i connect Nodejs with live server then error occur
Help me to remove this error
Server is running on http://localhost:5000
Connected to MySQL database.
node:events:492
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
at Connection._handleProtocolError (D:\ReactNativeProjects\ClickLife Project\Server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:423:8)
at Protocol.emit (node:events:514:28)
at Protocol._delegateError (D:\ReactNativeProjects\ClickLife Project\Server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:10)
at Protocol.handleNetworkError (D:\ReactNativeProjects\ClickLife Project\Server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:371:10)
at Connection._handleNetworkError (D:\ReactNativeProjects\ClickLife Project\Server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:418:18)
at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -4077,
code: 'ECONNRESET',
syscall: 'read',
fatal: true
}
Node.js v20.9.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
I have a hostinger MySQL live server and I have a react native cli project with the backend is Nodejs with MySQL. Problem is when i connect Nodejs with localhost MySQL then its properly work fine but when i connect Nodejs with live server then error occur
Help me to remove this error

Have you asked Hostinger for their configuration suggestions to connect Nodejs to MySQL?  Surely they have needed this connection in the past few years.

You may find this URL to be helpful for your project.  https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/1583546-how-to-set-up-remote-mysql-access
